# iPhone/iPod & iPad - Limitatios about Universal applications

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal-binary

Are there any limitation in writing universal application for iPhone and iPad ? (or the choice it's only about the code re-usability/design )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading the apple documentation, seams that there are no well-known limitation.
The choice between a universal application and 2 separated application it's only about the project design.